# vdebug - vim : not working

Tags: linux, vim, xdebug

I am using archlinux and installed gvim and python. THen using vundle in vim, installed the plugin vdebug for vim.

I am debugging a lot of php code for last 1 year using vdebug very successfully. Suddenly from yesterday i get the following errors in vim.

Exact sequence:

I open index.php using vim.

Press F5. In the bottom it shows `Waiting for a connection (Ctrl-C to cancel, this message will self-destruct in  20  seconds...)`

Then go to my browser and refresh the link: http://www.mylocalsite.com/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1

Generally afte this the debugging starts. But since yesterday nothing happens. it keeps showing `Waiting for a connection (Ctrl-C to cancel, this message will self-destruct in 20 seconds...)` so after some time 40 sec, if i type **enter** it shows the **output1** . Later I again closed the terminal and run all the steps except this time type **ctrl + c** instead of enter, it shows **output2**

**OUTPUT1**

```
    Waiting for a connection (Ctrl-C to cancel, this message will self-destruct in  20  seconds...)
    An error occured: <class 'vim.error'>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/simha/.vim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/start_vdebug.py", line 31, in run
        self.runner.run()
      File "/home/simha/.vim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/vdebug/runner.py", line 160, in run
        self.open()
      File "/home/simha/.vim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/vdebug/runner.py", line 47, in open
        self.ui.open()
      File "/home/simha/.vim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/vdebug/ui/vimui.py", line 75, in open
        raise e
    error: Vim(new):E325: ATTENTION
```

**Output2**

```
    Error detected while processing :
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/simha/.vim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/start_vdebug.py", line 31, in run
        self.runner.run()
      File "/home/simha/.vim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/vdebug/runner.py", line 160, in run
        self.open()
      File "/home/simha/.vim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/vdebug/runner.py", line 47, in open
        self.ui.open()
      File "/home/simha/.vim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/vdebug/ui/vimui.py", line 52, in open
        self.watchwin.create()
      File "/home/simha/.vim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/python/vdebug/ui/vimui.py", line 337, in create
        vim.command('silent ' + self.open_cmd + ' ' + self.name)
    KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that there is a swap file .Debugger.swp because of which the dedugger is not working. I have deleted that file. it started working

Also any other swp files made by vdebug are also removed.